# Rewrite $\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{1-y^2} \int_{0}^{1-y} dz \ dx \ dy$ in the five other orders of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I'm struggling to find limits of integration when the outermost integral depends on $x$ and $z$.

For example, when we study the shadow of the region on the $xz$-plane, we find that it's a square. But its projection upwards (in the direction of the positive $y$ axis) depends on two different surfaces (the cylinder $1-y^2$ and the plane $1-y$), and I don't know how to express everything in terms of one variable.

How can I approach these kinds of exercises?

**Edit**: my textbook says we should verify the following equalities

$$z = 1 - y \iff y = 1- z \\ x = 1 - y^2 \ \  \underset\iff{y\geq0} \ \ y = \sqrt{1-x}$$

Therefore

$$x = z^2 - 2z \\ z=1-\sqrt{1-x}$$

But what are these surfaces bounds of? I'm really confused.

Comment: I recommend drawing pictures, at least to get used to the game here. Trying to do it purely algebraically is not recommended. You might check out [this lecture on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miSfMprNByQ&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=62&t=9s) and perhaps the next one, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest (and easiest) way to approach this kind of problems is to look straight at the limits of integration.

The domain can be described by the following inequalities.
$$0\leq y \leq 1,\ 0\leq x \leq 1-y^2,\ 0\leq z\leq 1-y $$
Those are equivalent to the following
$$0\leq z\leq 1, \ 0\leq x\leq 1,\ y^2 \leq 1-x, \  0\leq y\leq 1-z $$
Well, the last two inequalities can be written as $0\leq y\leq \min (\sqrt{1-x},\ 1-z)$.
This leaves us with $$0\leq z\leq 1,\ 0\leq x\leq 1,\ 0\leq y\leq \min (\sqrt{1-x},\ 1-z) $$ and the integral can be written as $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{\min (\sqrt{1-x},\ 1-z)} dydxdz. $$